# Add multiple orderby with pre get posts

Tags: categories, archives, sort

I am already using a small code to set default sort orderby a custom field called "Year" I need to add another orderby to also sort by "Post Title" in the same sort.

**Sort** = Year-Customfield (DESC) and Post-title (ASC)

Following is the code I'm currently using to sort by Year DESC.

```
add_filter('pre_get_posts', 'sort_arc');
function sort_arc($q) {
 if ($q->is_category) {
   $q->set('orderby', 'meta_value_num');
   $q->set('meta_key', 'the-year');
   $q->set('order', 'DESC');
 }
 return $q;
}
```

Thanx

------------------EDIT---------------------------------

The Code that stopped working, as explained below

```
add_action('pre_get_posts', 'check_meta_sort');
function check_meta_sort($query) {
if( $query->is_admin == 1 ) {
return;
    }
if( !$query->is_main_query() ) {
return;
}
if( !$query->is_archive == 1 ) {
return;
}
$custom_field = ( $_GET['sort'] ) ? stripslashes( $_GET['sort'] ) : '';
$custom_value = ( $_GET['sortorder'] ) ? stripslashes( $_GET['sortorder'] ) : '';
if( $custom_field ) {
$query->set( 'meta_key', $custom_field );
$query->set( 'orderby', $custom_field );
if( $custom_value ) {
$query->set( 'order', $custom_value );
}
}
}
```

Comment: The second block is very different from the first. I think I get it but please explain in human terms what you want to do. (Looks like you are trying to alter the query based on URL parameters.) In what way does this not work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try using the `posts_orderby` filter:

```
add_filter('pre_get_posts', 'sort_arc');
function sort_arc($q) {
 if ($q->is_category() && $q->is_main_query()) {
    $q->set('meta_key', 'the-year');
    add_filter('posts_orderby', 'custom_posts_orderby');
 }
 return $q;
}
```

where

```
function custom_posts_orderby($orderby) {
    global $wpdb;
    return $wpdb->postmeta.".meta_value+0 DESC, ".$wpdb->posts .".post_title ASC";
}
```

takes care of the custom ordering. We use `meta_value+0` from the `meta_value_num`  definition in `/wp-includes/query.php`.

**Update:**

Here is one idea how you could try to combine the two hooks:

```
add_filter('pre_get_posts', 'custom_pre_get_posts');
function custom_pre_get_posts($q) {
    if( $q->is_admin ) {
        return $q;
    }
    if( !$q->is_main_query() ) {
        //echo "DEBUG: !is_main_query() <pre>".print_r($q,true)."</pre>";
        return $q;
    }
    if( !$q->is_archive() ) {
        //echo "DEBUG: !is_archive() <pre>".print_r($q,true)."</pre>";
        return $q;
    }
    if ($q->is_category() && !isset($_GET['sort']) ) {
        $q->set('meta_key', 'the-year');
        add_filter('posts_orderby', 'custom_posts_orderby');
        //echo "DEBUG: is_category() <pre>".print_r($q,true)."</pre>";
        return $q;
    }
    $custom_field = ( $_GET['sort'] ) ? stripslashes( $_GET['sort'] ) : '';
    $custom_value = ( $_GET['sortorder'] ) ? stripslashes( $_GET['sortorder'] ) : '';
    if( $custom_field ) {
        $q->set( 'meta_key', $custom_field );
        $q->set( 'orderby', $custom_field );
        if( $custom_value ) {
            $q->set( 'order', $custom_value );
            //echo "DEBUG: custom_value <pre>".print_r($q,true)."</pre>";
            return $q;
        }
        //echo "DEBUG: custom_field <pre>".print_r($q,true)."</pre>";
        return $q;
    }
    //echo "DEBUG: else <pre>".print_r($q,true)."</pre>";
    return $q;
}
```

Comment: Thanx Birgire, 

That works well, but it has made my other function stop working, The other function allows user to sort by Year ASC and DESC. I have edited the main post to add new code.

Comment: Revo, I'm sorry but that did not work. The sorting function still does not work.

Comment: Maybe you could add extra conditions in the if-sentence, like `!isset($_GET['sort']) && !isset($_GET['sortorder'])`?

Comment: Birgire, I'm not sure how I can do that, can you please elaborate?

Comment: by the way do you have to pre_get_posts hooks? Can you combine them into one filter?

Comment: missing w in my above comment, replace to with two  ;-)

Comment: The only reason I have two hooks is because I don't know how to combine them. One hook would be great!

Comment: I updated the answer, you could try to play with that.

Comment: O0ps that returns a Fatal error: Call to undefined method WP_Query::is_admin()

Comment: To test, I did remove 
`    if( $q->is_admin() ) {
        return $q;
    }`
The error went away, but sort does not work.

Comment: ahh, it should be $q->is_admin. I also added some debug lines that you can comment out. Use that to check where you are in the if-sentences. That should give some debug info to play with.

Comment: The first 3 echo work fine, the last three do not print with the parameters.

Comment: I added !isset($_GET['sort']), maybe that will help?

Comment: Yes! Woho! That works ... Many Many Many Thanx!
Now the only problem is that, the user "sorted" is not arranged by "Post Title" ASC, it seems random or by the date added. Can this be made ASC as we did for default sort?

Comment: great ;-)  I have to go now, but hopefully you can play with it some more ps: I'm not sure where the user part comes from.

Comment: can the add_filter('posts_orderby', 'custom_posts_orderby'); part also be applied for the  $custom_field sort? As of now it only sorts by Year ASC, Year DESC but does not second sort by post title.

Answer (score 0):

According to @birgire answer and your comment:

change your second snippet `add_action` to `add_filter` then set priorities for their execution.

In your case this should work:

```
add_filter('pre_get_posts', 'check_meta_sort', 9); // earlier execution
add_filter('pre_get_posts', 'sort_arc', 10);
```

Comment: @NaveenNarale how about not to changing `add_action` but just the priorities?

Comment: `add_action('pre_get_posts', 'check_meta_sort', 9); 
add_filter('pre_get_posts', 'sort_arc', 10);`


That did not work, let me know if I'm missing anything here.